# efficient XPath syntax exclusively extract single component

Tags: html, xpath, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

Using the Firefox-Aurora I determined the following HTML snippet from this website: `http://www.zdic.net/z/19/js/5DCD.htm`.

I want to extract only the component `丨フ丨ノ一丨ノ丶フノ一ノ丨フ一一ノフフ丶`.

It's located near the bottom of the following code block:

```
<tr>

<td class="z_i_t4_uno" align="center">

    <a href="http://www.unicode.org/cgi-bin/GetUnihanData.pl?codepoint=5DCD" target="_blank"> 

        <img src="/images/unicode2.gif" border="0" align="absmiddle">

    </a> 

    U+5DCD

</td>

<td class="z_i_t4" align="center">

    <span class="diczx7">

        MTVC

    </span>

</td>

<td class="z_i_t4" align="center">

    <span class="diczx7">

        UHVI

    </span>

</td>

<td class="z_i_t4" align="center">

    <span class="diczx7">

        LLZN

    </span>

</td>

<td style="background-color: transparent;" class="z_i_t4" align="center">

    <span class="diczx6">

        22413

    </span>

</td>

<td class="z_i_t4" align="center">

    <span id="z_i_t2_bis" title="竖折竖撇横竖撇捺折撇横撇竖折横横撇折折捺">

    丨フ丨ノ一丨ノ丶フノ一ノ丨フ一一ノフフ丶

    </span>

</td>
```

I've been trying different XPath sequences pin it down with the help of this website: `http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath` but I can't seem to get hold of it.

Something like `//title[@td]` results in

```
WARNING - Processing of namespace declaration [//title[@td]] failed.    Right format: PREFIX=NAMESPACE. Declaration skipped.
ERROR - Seem there is no XPath provided?
```

How can I make sure I only collect that sequence and nothing else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning and error you get are specific to the site you are using to test your XPath expression. It appears you have used a syntax that is used to declare namespaces on http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath.

Given that you know how to submit an XPath expression, the following works fine:

```
//td[@class = 'z_i_t4'][last()]/span/text()
```

and gives you only the wanted text node:

```
丨フ丨ノ一丨ノ丶フノ一ノ丨フ一一ノフフ丶
```

Comment: i tried that in the scrapy shell and it rejected it with the message 'Syntax Error; invalud syntax' and points me to the 4 in t4

Comment: @flavius_valens I very much doubt that it said "invalud syntax" but anyway, that's definitely a correct XPath expression. I cannot comment on how you _use_ this Xpath expression in Scrapy - you do not show any code and you made it look as if you are using an online XPath site for testing.

Comment: i tried this thing << id('z_i_t2_bis') >> which i got from a firefox xpath extractor add on and that returned a bunch of random numbers, not quite sure whats goin on there, anyway, i guess you're code is right, i think scrapy is just sort of weird, i need to play around with it a bit more. PS disregard the << >> above, they're used to present the snippet only

Answer (score -3):

try this code

```
xpath=tr/td/span[@id='z_i_t2_bis']
```

Comment: Could you please explain how this answer is related to the question? Where is XInclude mentioned there? Any why do you store an XPath expression as an XPointer?

Comment: Now that you've changed the answer completely; Most likely the expression will not find anything because there is no `//` in front of it, and if it does, it returns the whole `span` element.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.